# jquery S.post and xmlhttprequest both do not give back result accessing localhost web server

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have developed a web server based on mqtt emqx which saves IoT data in a Sqlite3 DB accessed by a local http sever python made on port 8080 to which a emqtx plugin routes data coming from connected IoT devices. So far so good. Now the problem is to fetch those data via nginx server on port 80 without a direct ws connection to the db handler not to expose it to internet but instead getting the data via html page under nginx calling the http python server on port 8080 by jQuery $.post or xmlhttprequest either. The bad news is that the call is executed on the python http server but the result is not received back by the jQuery call which gives error instead.

If I send the request to the http python server by a node.js client or by a python requests client everything is fine so I do not understand why the access made by jquery in the browser can't get the result. Currently my application is working fine accessing the DB driver by web socket but I wanted to avoid exposing the DB access in the net. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Note: All above stuff runs in a Linux Docker container

Comment: jQuery and JavaScript run in a Browser. Your statement, *the call is executed on the python http server but the result is not received back by the jQuery* does not make any sense. Are you creating an HTTP Call in Python to send data? What are you expecting to happen? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What I mean is that the browser fetched the html page from local file C:/xxx/client.html , then executed  $.post("http://localhost:8080",query..), the python httpserv on localhost:8080 received and executed the request as shown in the log, the result was sent via self.wfile.write(res) but the browser showed error instead of res. It seems to be a cross-domain issue even though everything runs on localhost. If the same post req is sent by a python requests client it receives the expected result.

Comment: Python does not care about the request source or destination. It will accept the request and handle output. The Browser might care, but it should be all the same local domain. So if you see an error in the Python Output, there is an issue in your Python script. I would create a stand alone test Form ( non-AJAX) and see if you can properly Post the data and get the expected result.

Comment: The python simple server works fine, no error at all , I suspect the problem is in the browser which demands both port and host to be the same from where the page was fetched and the jquery request target. In my case I fetch from port 80 and call the port 8080 on the python http server. I decided to redesign my application using python flask both for html pages and DB access on a single port.